# Some phones need permission READ_CONTACTS to read from contact picker

Tags: java, android, permissions

I have a **HTC ONE M7** (GPE 4.2.2) and **HTC EVO 3D** (4.0.3) HTC Sense 3.6

**HTC ONE** does not need:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

on **HTC EVO 3D** however, following code throws an exception:

```
 public static String getPhoneNumberFromIntent(Context context, Intent data) throws SecurityException {
    String contactNumber = null;
    final Uri contactUri = data.getData();
    if (contactUri != null) {
        Cursor c = null;
        try {
            // Read contact number from contacts provider
            String[] projection = new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
            c = context.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
            if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                int maxNumberLength = context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.max_phone_number_cze);
                contactNumber = cutOnlyLastPhoneNumberDigits(c.getString(0), maxNumberLength);
            }
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                c.close();
            }
        }
    }
    return contactNumber;
}
```

-

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.HtcContactsProvider2
uri content://com.android.contacts/data/2158 from pid=14938, uid=10125 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
```

I have read that appliaction is granted required permissions when user selects contact by hand. However on some phones this does not work (HTC EVO 3D).

Why is this happending? Is there a workaround such is ability to ask for this permission at runtime ?

Comment: Just FYI, I encountered this problem as well, on several Sony and HTC models.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> HTC ONE does not need: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />` on HTC EVO 3D however, following code throws an exception

If the `Uri` you are getting is coming from `ACTION_PICK` or `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, whether or not you have temporary read permissions for that contact will vary by contact-picking app.

> I have read that appliaction is granted required permissions when user selects contact by hand. However on some phones this does not work (HTC EVO 3D).

There is no requirement that all contact-picking apps grant you temporary read access to the contact. In fact, I am unclear if third-party contact managers would have the ability to grant you temporary read access to the contact.

> Is there a workaround such is ability to ask for this permission at runtime ?

You cannot change your mix of candidate permissions at runtime.

Your choices are:

1. Always ask for `READ_CONTACTS` in the manifest. This ensures you can do what you want, at the cost of requesting another permission, one that prospective users might not like.
2. Handle the `SecurityException` and simply do without the data that you are trying to `query()`, if that data is not essential.
3. Write a separate app with the `READ_CONTACTS` permission that can serve as a "plugin" for your app, securely retrieving contact data on behalf of your main app. You can then route users who get the `SecurityException` to install your contacts plugin. This is tricky to write without introducing security flaws, so I would encourage you to use either of the other options.

Comment: Actually official Android docs says that starting from Android 2.3 we don't have to ask this permission: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html (bottom notes). Although you are right that 3rd party apps may not include correct permission for us and this is confusing.

Comment: Seems that some manufacturers use too old code base for their apps:)

Answer (score 0):

You can't ask permission at run-time. You can only add a level API to your permission for example:

```
<uses-permission
     android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
     android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

It means that the permission is no needed if api is 19 or higher.

Comment: It seems that this permission does not depend on api version.

Comment: I know. I answered to your question about the possiblity to ask the permission at run-time, the response is no. The only thing you can do in general with a permission is what I wrote