# Why some phones don't need intent filter?

Tags: android, android-intent

This is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23997210/some-phones-need-permission-read-contacts-to-read-from-contact-picker) but not exactly the same. I'm not asking how to ask permission on runtime.

I am working on nfc in android and thus I need permission like

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
</intent-filter>
```

However, in samsung(SM-N900L), I only need to catch the newIntent using

```
String action = intent.getAction();
if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
        || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
        || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
    resolveIntent(intent);
}
```

Basically, my question is, why is that in samsung I don't need the intent filter, but in other phone I need the filters?

**Foreground config**

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (hasNfcAdapter()) {
        if (!mAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "NFC is disabled.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, null, null);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (hasNfcAdapter())
        mAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}

protected void initNfc() {
    mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if (mAdapter != null) {
        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    }
}

protected boolean hasNfcAdapter() {
    return mAdapter != null;
}
```

Comment: Is this all your NFC-related code? Could it be that you register for the foreground dispatch system or something like that?

Comment: @MichaelRoland I'm so sorry for the late reply, yes I register for the foreground dispatch, I think that is necessary? I just followed the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html)

Comment: You only need the intent filter in the AndroidManifest.xml when you want your app to be **started** by an NFC tag. If you want to detect the events while your activity is active in the foreground, the foreground dispatch is sufficient. Hence, if your app does not work without the intent filter on some devices, you most probably have a mistake in configuring the foreground dispatch.

Comment: @MichaelRoland ok, but here's the thing, I tried my app in multiple devices but it doesn't work aside from samsung. When I tried putting the intent filter, it worked. Also, I got the foreground configuration from the android docs.

Comment: Well, then show how you configured the foreground dispatch...

Comment: @MichaelRoland hold on

Comment: Are you using the above code to check the intent in `onNewIntent(Intent intent)`?

Comment: Did you use `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />` (note that this is case-sensitive) to request the permission to use NFC?

Comment: Yes, I have that permission.

Comment: That's odd, the only difference that I see to the code that I typically use is that I explicitly pass `new IntentFilter[]{ new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED) }` as the third parameter to `enableForegroundDispatch`, but according to the API documentation this should be the same as passing `null`.

Comment: That's why I concluded that it is because of Samsung.

Comment: Well, it would be because of all the **other** OEMs then, since the behavior on the Samsung device is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question should be asked to Samsung.

Usually vendors can change the Android OS as they wish and looks like Samsung has changed behavior in this case.