# Should I have permission READ_CONTACTS if I read contact from native android app?

Tags: android

I want to read contact like this

Should I ask permission for this?

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI)
        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_PICK_CONTACT)
```

Comment: yes you should ask for permission in manifest and programmatically

Comment: But my app work without this in production and it works normal. I declared in manifest only. And I tested in emulator and in Android 8.0 , 9.0 phone. It works normal

Comment: You are supposed to have access to the contact returned by `ACTION_PICK` without holding `READ_CONTACTS`. However, [that is not guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23997708/115145).

Answer (score 1):

Android platform is moving towards creating a more user-safe experience. There are new safety features coming out that gives the user an option to only enable certain features for the session that the user is during the app's usage. It makes sense to be explicit about these permissions with the end user so they feel more clear about how they will expose themselves.